# How to apply recursive naming to split documents (e.g. DreamFile01.docx,Dream_File02.docx, etc.)

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have a script which splits a word document to separate word documents. Each split document is 1 page.

What is the modification needed, to have each split document be named recursively like 
Dream_File01.docx,Dream_File02.docx, Dream_File03.docx,Dream_File04.docx,Dream_File05.docx,Dream_File06.docx, etc.

```
## -- Settings --
#$fileNamePattern = "ID #:\s+(\d+)"
$fileNamePattern = "Student ID #:\s+# (\d+)"
$pageLength = 1

$inputFile = "Dream_File.docx"
$outputPath = "outputDir\" #End the path with a slash

## -- End Settings


[ref]$SaveFormat = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveFormat" -as [type] 
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.Visible = $true

$doc = $word.Documents.Open($inputFile)
$pages = $doc.ComputeStatistics([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic]::wdStatisticPages)

$rngPage = $doc.Range()

for($i=1;$i -le $pages; $i+=$pageLength)
{
    [Void]$word.Selection.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem]::wdGoToPage,
                         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,
                         $i #Starting Page
                         )
        $rngPage.Start = $word.Selection.Start

    [Void]$word.Selection.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem]::wdGoToPage,
                         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,
                         $i+$pageLength #Next page Number
                         )
    $rngPage.End = $word.Selection.Start

    $marginTop = $word.Selection.PageSetup.TopMargin
    $marginBottom = $word.Selection.PageSetup.BottomMargin
    $marginLeft = $word.Selection.PageSetup.LeftMargin
    $marginRight = $word.Selection.PageSetup.RightMargin



    $rngPage.Copy()
    $newDoc = $word.Documents.Add()

    $word.Selection.PageSetup.TopMargin = $marginTop 
    $word.Selection.PageSetup.BottomMargin = $marginBottom
    $word.Selection.PageSetup.LeftMargin = $marginLeft
    $word.Selection.PageSetup.RightMargin = $marginRight

    $word.Selection.Paste() # Now we have our new page on a new doc
    $word.Selection.EndKey(6,0) #Move to the end of the file
    $word.Selection.TypeBackspace() #Seems to grab an extra section/page break
    $word.Selection.Delete() #Now we have our doc down to size

    #Get Name
    $regex = [Regex]::Match($rngPage.Text, $fileNamePattern)
    if($regex.Success)
    {
        $id = $regex.Groups[1].Value
    }
    else
    {
        $id = "patternNotFound_" + $i 
    }

    $path = $outputPath + $id + ".docx"
    $newDoc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault) 
    $newDoc.close() 

    Remove-Variable(regex)
    Remove-Variable(id) 

}


[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: this `for($i=1;$i -le $pages; $i+=$pageLength)` provides you with a counter. have you tried using that? ///// also, what is the _current_ output of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired output is a series of Word documents called `Dream_File_01.docx`,`Dream_File_02.docx` etc. then I do nut fully understand why you would want to use a regex to get the `StudentID`.

As Lee_Dailey already commented, the page counter needed for the sequential naming is already present in the `$i` variable.

Anyway, here's my modifications to your script. Please read the comments I've put in there so you can make your choice in either using the `StudentID` or not:

```
## -- Settings --
#$fileNamePattern = "ID #:\s+(\d+)"
$fileNamePattern = "Student ID #:\s+# (\d+)"
$pageLength = 1

$inputFile  = "Dream_File.docx"
$outputPath = "outputDir" # Use Join-Path so don't worry about it not ending with a backslash.

## -- End Settings

[ref]$SaveFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat" -as [type] 
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true

$doc     = $word.Documents.Open($inputFile)
$pages   = $doc.ComputeStatistics([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic]::wdStatisticPages)
$rngPage = $doc.Range()

for($i = 1; $i -le $pages; $i += $pageLength) {
    [void]$word.Selection.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem]::wdGoToPage,
                         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,
                         $i #Starting Page
                         )
    $rngPage.Start = $word.Selection.Start

    [void]$word.Selection.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem]::wdGoToPage,
                         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,
                         $i+$pageLength #Next page Number
                         )
    $rngPage.End = $word.Selection.Start

    $marginTop    = $word.Selection.PageSetup.TopMargin
    $marginBottom = $word.Selection.PageSetup.BottomMargin
    $marginLeft   = $word.Selection.PageSetup.LeftMargin
    $marginRight  = $word.Selection.PageSetup.RightMargin

    $rngPage.Copy()
    $newDoc = $word.Documents.Add()

    $word.Selection.PageSetup.TopMargin    = $marginTop 
    $word.Selection.PageSetup.BottomMargin = $marginBottom
    $word.Selection.PageSetup.LeftMargin   = $marginLeft
    $word.Selection.PageSetup.RightMargin  = $marginRight

    $word.Selection.Paste()         # Now we have our new page on a new doc
    $word.Selection.EndKey(6,0)     # Move to the end of the file
    $word.Selection.TypeBackspace() # Seems to grab an extra section/page break
    $word.Selection.Delete()        # Now we have our doc down to size

    # This part I don't fully understand..
    # Why do you want to get the Student ID number here? Should that be part of the filename?
    # Can you be sure that on every page this number can be found? 
    $regex = [Regex]::Match($rngPage.Text, $fileNamePattern)
    if($regex.Success) {
        # Get the filename without extension from the $inputFile string and append the student ID, the pagecounter '$i' and '.docx' extension to it
        $newFileName = '{0}_{1}_{2:00}.docx' -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($inputFile), $regex.Groups[1].Value, $i
    }
    else {
        # Get the filename without extension from the $inputFile string and append 'patternNotFound', the pagecounter '$i' and '.docx' extension to it
        $newFileName = '{0}_patternNotFound_{1:00}.docx' -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($inputFile), $i
    }

    # If the Student ID is not needed in the filename, use this instead:
    # Get the filename without extension from the $inputFile string and append the pagecounter '$i' and '.docx' extension to it
    # $newFileName = '{0}_{1:00}.docx' -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($inputFile), $i

    # next combine the output path with the new filename for Save()
    $path = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath $newFileName

    $newDoc.SaveAs([ref] $path, [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault) 
    $newDoc.Close() 
}

# you're done, exit Word and clean up the Com object
$word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null 
[System.GC]::Collect() 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Hope that helps